# Postman is sending request right away when clicking on tab

Tags: postman

I clicked on the tab (opened for 2 weeks) with data that I wanted to change and send and then it sent the request right away before I had a chance to change it to anything.

Is it an expected behavior?
Can I change it?

UPDATE1: I checked and that only works when clicking on the example tab, it's version 10.16.0

Comment: It would be great if you can add steps to reproduce it or some evidence, and then ask this on Postman Github issues.